# Input on multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I try to write a short program which takes multiple pdf files and merges them into one file. The whole thing should operate over a command line.

I use the argparse-package from python. The program works when I call it and give exactly two files to merge. But I want it to be more flexible. Concrete, what I want to do is calling the program, give the first file and hit enter. Then it should ask for the second file: I give it and hit enter, and so on until I hit enter without inserting any file. Like this, the program should know that all files are given.
Every time I hit enter, the program executes and I don't have any chance to do anything else. I searched for a workaround but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input`:

```
files = []
file = input("Your file: ").strip()
while file:
    files.append(file)
    file = input("Your file: ").strip()

print(f"Files to process: {files}")
```